# Set options such as "num spaces" in Doctrine Symfony

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm, doctrine

I know in the doctrine bin, you can generate entities and also set the num spaces as well.

`vendor/bin/doctrine orm:generate-entities src/ --generate-annotations=true --regenerate-entities --num-spaces=2`

However, I don't think symfony's app/console lets you do that.   Symfony doesn't have a vendor/bin when firing up a new project as well, so I can't perform the command above.  Is there a way to go about bringing back these options?

Comment: You cannot add the option via app/console but if you install Symfony via Composer you should get a doctrine executable in bin/doctrine? (not vendor/bin/doctrine)

Comment: wow, I am blind.  thanks @dchesterton !